# Check if SQL table exists in Tarantool

Tags: sql, tarantool

How can I check in Tarantool SQL if a table already exists?

Answer (score 4):

Using only SQL facilities it can be done this way:

```
SELECT EXISTS (select true from "_space" where "name" = 'table_name')
```

For instance:

```
tarantool> SELECT EXISTS (select true from "_space" where "name" = 'T1')
---
- metadata:
  - name: EXISTS (select true from "_space" where "name" = 'T1')
    type: boolean
  rows:
  - [true]
...

tarantool> SELECT EXISTS (select true from "_space" where "name" = 'T')
---
- metadata:
  - name: EXISTS (select true from "_space" where "name" = 'T')
    type: boolean
  rows:
  - [false]
...
```

In Lua mode:

```
tarantool> box.space.T1 ~= nil
---
- true
...

tarantool> box.space.T ~= nil
---
- false
...
```

Comment: Comparing to `nil` is only necessary if you explicitly want a boolean type or want to specifically express then and there the intent of checking for existance. Otherwise you can just do `if box.space.T1 then print 'yes' else print 'no' end` or `print(box.space.T1 and 'yes' or 'no')` :D